# d.ts interface augmentations being recognized by IDE but not by TSC

Tags: express, typescript

I am using ES6 style module inclusion within webstorm and I have an express app which has a custom d.ts (For middleware which alters objects) which looks something like this:

```
declare module Express {
    export interface Application {
        getLogger(): LoggerInstance;
        getRepository(collectionName): IRepository;
        getEnvironmentVars(): any;
    }
}
```

Now the IDE sees this and whenever I were to use it there are no errors, however when I run this through TSC it blows up saying `'getRepository' does not exist on type 'Application'`

I have plenty of other d.ts files which are working fine but there are no errors listed and nothing odd I can see there.

An example use case of this may be:

```
import { Express } from "express"

export function SomeMiddleWare(app: Express){...};
```

(Express in the express.d.ts extends Application which contains the augmentations in the other file.)

So I am baffled as to why it works in the IDE but not in the TSC, which is including all the *.d.ts files within a typing directory, there are no errors being listed with the d.ts files just with the usages which are defined in this specific d.ts.

Comment: What params/config are you using to run tsc?

Comment: It is being run through gulp-typescript and it is being passed the source files and typing files. I know this works as its exactly the same build script used for 5 other projects which follow same convention (`src` folder for source files, `typing` folder for type files), it includes all ts in source in all sub directories and all d.ts files in sub directories in the typings folder. Also I have 3 other custom d.ts files which extend mongodb and other libs and they are all being used correctly and live in the same folder as this d.ts file which is not behaving.

Answer (score 0):

> TSC it blows up saying 'getRepository' does not exist on type 'Application'

Make sure that this new `.d.ts` is included in the compilation context for tsc using something like `tsconfig.json`

Comment: After a few hours of trying different things the actual issue seems to be related to it not being able to import the IRepository type, but silently fails and just then ignores the rest of the d.ts, if I set everything to return type `any` it all works fine.